# Ошибка в создание Маршрутов класса контроллера

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest

Подскажите пожалуйста где была допущена ошибка ? при любом запросе к api возникают ошибки

```
class Rest_api_app
{
    public function prefix_register_example_routes() 
    {
        $namespace = 'api/app/';
        
        register_rest_route( $namespace, 'cameras', array(
            'methods'  => 'GET',
            'callback' => array($this,'get_camers'),
        ));
    }
    public function get_camers() 
    {
        return rest_ensure_response("xxxx");
    }
        
}


$plugin_app_api = new Rest_api_app();
add_action( 'rest_api_init',$plugin_app_api , 'prefix_register_example_routes' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы некорректно передаёте аргументы при добавлении экшена. Нужно передавать вот так

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', [$plugin_app_api , 'prefix_register_example_routes' ] );
```

Подробнее о создании экшенов вы можете почитать здесь https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_action